# Bounding values of vector : Thresholding function

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

```
 H = [1 1; 1 2; 2 -1; 2 0; -1 2; -2 1; -1 -1; -2 -2;]';
```

I need to threshold each value such that

```
H(I,j) = 0 if H(I,j) > =1,
else H(I,j) = 1 if H(I,j) <=0
```

I applied this code

```
  a = H(1,1) 
    a(a<=0) = 1

    a(a>=1) = 0
```

But this means that the already affected value in the first step may get changed again. What is the correct way of thresholding? The above code is giving incorrect answers. I should be getting

```
a = [0 0; 0 0; 0 1;  0 1;  1 0;  1 0;   1 1;   1 1]
```

Please help

**EDIT**

Based upon the answer now I am getting

```
         0         0
         0         0
    1.0000    0.3443
    0.8138    0.9919
         0    0.7993
    0.1386    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000
```

As can be seen, rows 3-6 are all incorrect. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ind1 = H>=1; %// get indices before doing any change
ind2 = H<=0;
H(ind1) = 0; %// then do the changes
H(ind2) = 1;
```

If dealing with non-integer values, you should apply a certain tolerance in the comparisons:

```
tol = 1e-6; %// example tolerance
ind1 = H>=1-tol; %// get indices before doing any change
ind2 = H<=0+tol;
H(ind1) = 0; %// then do the changes
H(ind2) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, which works but not for all cases. For instance, there are some real number values which are getting unaffected. I have updated my question above. Please have a look at the real number values and how do I limit them in the range>

Comment: @SKM That's probably [the usual problem with comparing floating values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab). To solve it, define a tolerance and apply it in the comparisons. See updated answer (second part)

Comment: I have done like this asI guess mythreshold function was incorrect. Is it now correct instead of applying the tolerance? ind1 = H>0;
ind2 = H<=0;
H(ind1) = 0;
H(ind2) = 1;

Comment: @SKM I don't know if it's correct because I don't know what you're trying to achieve. But when comparing real (floating point) numbers you sould always apply a tolerance

Comment: I am trying to apply various thresholding function used to squash the outputs of neural network. Thresholding functions like Sigmoid, hard limit etc. For instance, in hard limit function the output should only be binary [0,1]; whereas sigmoid gives continuous real values.